# Is there a canonical date for Returning Day?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, time

Returning Day apparently celebrates the day that Balduran returned to Gray Harbor. Does any source give a specific date that this occurs on, in the Harptos Calendar?

Comment: Someone asked for this information on twitter some time ago but no response from Ed yet: https://twitter.com/JayPalThrasher/status/1106028752750952448.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There doesn't seem to be

Murder In Baldur's Gate, the primary source on the festival's existence, doesn't mention any dates, and is in general somewhat vague about what happens in the Day itself. The only hint towards a possible estimate is in the descriptions of the events, such as:

> The light drizzle isn’t dampening the festive mood [...]

(Murder in Baldur's Gate, page 4, under *It begins with blood*)

As very little sources on Returning Day exist, it's likely no date has ever been officially announced.

As Murder in Baldur's Gate seems to be the only officially published book that mentions Returning Day, I believe there are no published dates for it.

Comment: If there are other reliable sources on Returning Day, I will revise my answer accordingly, but so far the only one I'm aware of existing is *Murder*, and all references to the event trace back to events only described in the book, thus my answer.